# Nameservers setup in CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, domain

I have a domain registered externally from where I have my VPS, but I need to connect these two in order to have the domain forward to my host. I know that I have to take my host's nameservers and replace them at my Domain Registrar's website.

The question is: Where do I get my nameservers?...

I've read about `/etc/resolv.conf` and I actually added my nameservers there like this:

```
ns1.mywebsite.org 8.8.8.8
ns2.mywebsite.org 8.8.4.4
```

The IPs are actually like that, I didn't know with what to replace them.

So how do I set up my nameservers correctly and have the domain point to my host?

**P.S: I'm using Webmin to manage my VPS.**

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption that *you have to take your host's nameservers and replace them at your Domain Registrar's website*  is not quite what you need to do.

---

First: You do not need to change the `/etc/resolv.conf` file on your host. That is the configuration file your host uses to resolve all internet domains/hostnames, not just your own. The ip-addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are public DNS servers provided by Google and suitable for most configurations. The configuration should look like:

```
# /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

---

Changing nameserver records is what you do when you run your own nameserver. Normally you do not need to run your own nameservers and you shouldn't try before improving your understanding of DNS.

I think that what you probably want to achieve is that people using for instance `www.yourdomain.com` end up at your VPS and e-mail addressed to `<someone>@yourdomain.com` also gets delivered to the mailserver you run on your host.

That is mostly updating the DNS records for www.yourdomain.com ftp.yourdomain.com etc. Typically your registrar provides a management console where you can do that yourself and your domain uses the nameservers from the registrar.

In that management console you enter the ip-address of your VPS as the `A-record` for `www.yourdomain.com` and  for all other DNS names you might want to use.

Comment: I'm aware of DNS records, but my host doesn't provide them since I'm not hosting my websites there. I had this feature available in the past, but now that I'm not continuing with their host, they removed this functionality and advised me to start using nameservers. And yes, you exactly described what I need, but I have to find an alternative way to achieve this without DNS Records setup at my Registrar.

Comment: Then transfer the domain to a registrar that does allow you to manage your domain...

Comment: The direction of this question is changing a little, but where do you recommend to transfer?

Comment: The first five results for searching on domain registration all include managing DNS records in their most basic product offering.

Comment: I would still like to continue solving this issue without transferring. I'd really appreciate some help with the nameservers.

Comment: Then it is simply a question of installing bind-chroot, configure it as an authoritive nameserver for your domain and then have the registrar use the ip-address of your VPS as the nameserver. The RedHat/CentOS [manual](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-DNS_Servers.html) is pretty conclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for /etc/resolv.conf is "nameserver $IP_ADDRESS", like, if you use Google's DNS, "nameserver 8.8.8.8". If you want to locally resolve ns1.mywebsite.org to a certain IP, edit /etc/hosts.